# Take a quote, and show how many characters, words, and average of each word

Tags: java, char

I am kinda new to Java, please do not tell me to use methods, etc. because I do not know how to do them. But I do know some charAt things, so can anyone help me find the amount of words, and avg of each word, i did the first part. Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FavouriteQuote {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String sQuote;
        int counter = 0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter one of your favourite quotes: ");
        sQuote = input.nextLine();
        input.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < sQuote.length(); i ++) {
            counter ++;
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
    }

}
```

Comment: perhaps the split() method for the string class will be helpful in finding words and a hashmap<string, int> for word counts. However I am confused as to what the average of each word is since you are only asking for input from the user once and then exiting so your average for the words will just be their word counts

Comment: If you're new then reading the documentation is really helpful. The String class has what you need... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz if OP knows he's only dealing with ASCII letters, then an array of ints is easier to deal with than a HashMap. But I agree the Map would be the correct thing to use for a larger CharSet

Comment: Average of each word as in ???

Answer (score 0):

But what average do you need? average word length in quote?
 then your code may look like:

```
    ...
    input.close();

    System.out.println("Characters in quote:" + sQuote.length());

    String[] words = sQuote.split("\\s");
    // or 
    // String[] words = sQuote.split(" ");

    System.out.println("words in quote:" + words.length);

    int totalWordsLength =0;
    for (String word: words) 
    {
        totalWordsLength = totalWordsLength + word.length();
    }
//or with loop counter
//      for (int i=0; i < words.length; i++) 
//      {
//          totalWordsLength += words[i].length();
//      }       

    System.out.println("average word length in quote:" + (totalWordsLength/ words.length));
```

Keep in mind: here average is `int` so it will be only integer portion of divide result. i.e. 11/3 = 3
BTW (aside of question) - You do not need your `for` loop. It does not make any sense. 
`counter = sQuote.length()` does the same.